# Launching an android app with a bluetooth device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

Like my title , I need to start an app remotely with a bluetooth device like a headphone.It can be when the bluetooth connection is ready or when a button is pressed on bluetooth device , it doesnt matter.The point is how to open app with bluetooth.I found somethings like BroadcastIntent,BroadcastReceiver...etc but I dont see any tutorial about this.Any advice ?

Comment: It's customary to tell us what you've already tried. How much Android programming experience do you have? AFAIK, there are no general utilities to do what you want (I could be wrong), so it's likely that you'd have to write a service to do this.

Comment: For about 2 years I am busy with android but generally I worked on ui.I am new on these broadcast,service stuffs